# How to change the language in multi lang project?

Tags: .net, vb.net, multilingual

I want to develop a muli-language windows app in vb.net.
I know how to change the language of form and how to switch between languages.
But the problem is that I don't know why it's not working for my language 'Persian'.
I can use English and dutch language and witch between them.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: What is multi language project? can you be more specific? how do you implement that feature? 'multi language' isn't a visual basic feature.

Comment: maybe you should have label database that contain text property for all controls in your app and use IMEmode = on ....

Comment: Assuming you mean "language for the user of the app", you'll probably want to look up and study "localization" of software applications. But briefly (and probably inadequately), it involves collecting all of the strings that are presented to the user in one or a small number of places in the software (a "string resource"), an instance of the string resource(s) per language desired, window planning to accommodate different length strings due to translations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to change the culture, then this will help.

```
Dim cultureInfo As System.Globalization.CultureInfo
cultureInfo = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo(language)

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo
```